# How can I get nth element from a list?

Tags: haskell

How can I access a list by index in Haskell, analog to this C code?

```c
int a[] = { 34, 45, 56 };
return a[1];
```

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Look [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html), the operator used is `!!`.

I.e. `[1,2,3]!!1` gives you `2`, since lists are 0-indexed.

Comment: Personally I can't comprehend how an at-index accessor that doesn't return a Maybe type is acceptable as idiomatic Haskell. `[1,2,3]!!6` will give you a runtime error. It could very easily be avoided if `!!` had the type `[a] -> Int -> Maybe a`. The very reason we have Haskell is to avoid such runtime errors!

Comment: It's a tradeoff. The symbol they chose is probably the most alarming symbol they could have. So I think the idea was to allows it for edge cases, but make it stand out as non-idiomatic.

Comment: ```itemOf :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a; x `itemOf` xs = let xslen = length xs in if ((abs x) > xslen) then Nothing else Just (xs !! (x `mod` xslen))```.  Note, this will fail catastrophically on an infinite list.

Comment: `!!` is a partial and thus unsafe function. Take a look at the comment below and use `lens` https://stackoverflow.com/a/23627631/2574719

Comment: @worldsayshi The same reason why division operator doesn't return `Maybe`. Some fundamental operators are useful expressed as a partial function. Of course, you should somehow prove that the precondition is met. And I agree, that it typically would be useful to have _both_ versions available, like `List.get` and `List.getOrNull` in Kotlin. Even an additional division operator possibly returning `DivideByZeroError` would be cool. But having _only_ the "safe" ones... I don't know, I wouldn't like that.

Answer (score 101):

I'm not saying that there's anything wrong with your question or the answer given, but maybe you'd like to know about the wonderful tool that is [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to save yourself time in the future: With Hoogle, you can search for standard library functions that match a given signature. So, not knowing anything about `!!`, in your case you might search for "something that takes an `Int` and a list of whatevers and returns a single such whatever", namely

```
Int -> [a] -> a
```

Lo and [behold](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20[a]%20-%3E%20a), with `!!` as the first result (although the type signature actually has the two arguments in reverse compared to what we searched for). Neat, huh?

Also, if your code relies on indexing (instead of consuming from the front of the list), lists may in fact not be the proper data structure. For O(1) index-based access there are more efficient alternatives, such as [arrays](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays) or [vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector).

Comment: Hoogle is absolutely great. Every Haskell programmer should know it. There is an alternative called Hayoo (http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html). It searches as you type but doesn't seem to be as clever as Hoogle.

Answer (score 73):

An alternative to using `(!!)` is to use the 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package and its `element` function and associated operators.  The 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) provides a uniform interface for accessing a wide variety of structures and nested structures above and beyond lists. Below I will focus on providing examples and will gloss over both the type signatures and the theory behind the 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package. If you want to know more about the theory a good place to start is the readme file at the [github repo](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/).

## Accessing lists and other datatypes

### Getting access to the lens package

At the command line:

```
$ cabal install lens
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
> import Control.Lens
```

### Accessing lists

To access a list with the infix operator

```
> [1,2,3,4,5] ^? element 2  -- 0 based indexing
Just 3
```

Unlike the `(!!)` this will not throw an exception when accessing an element out of bounds and will return `Nothing` instead.  It is often recommend to avoid partial functions like `(!!)` or `head` since they have more corner cases and are more likely to cause a run time error. You can read a little more about why to avoid partial functions at [this wiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Avoiding_partial_functions).

```
> [1,2,3] !! 9
*** Exception: Prelude.(!!): index too large

> [1,2,3] ^? element 9
Nothing
```

You can force the lens technique to be a partial function and throw an exception when out of bounds by using the `(^?!)` operator instead of the `(^?)` operator.

```
> [1,2,3] ^?! element 1
2
> [1,2,3] ^?! element 9
*** Exception: (^?!): empty Fold
```

### Working with types other than lists

This is not just limited to lists however.  For example the same technique works on [trees](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Tree.html) from the standard 
[containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package.

```
 > import Data.Tree
 > :{
 let
  tree = Node 1 [
       Node 2 [Node 4[], Node 5 []]
     , Node 3 [Node 6 [], Node 7 []]
     ]
 :}
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $tree
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  `- 5
|
`- 3
   |
   +- 6
   |
   `- 7
```

We can now access the elements of the tree in depth-first order:

```
> tree ^? element 0
Just 1
> tree ^? element 1
Just 2
> tree ^? element 2
Just 4
> tree ^? element 3
Just 5
> tree ^? element 4
Just 3
> tree ^? element 5
Just 6
> tree ^? element 6
Just 7
```

We can also access [sequences](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) from the
[containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package:

```
> import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
> Seq.fromList [1,2,3,4] ^? element 3
Just 4
```

We can access the standard int indexed arrays from the 
[vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package, text from the standard 
[text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package, bytestrings fro the standard
[bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) package, and many other standard data structures.  This standard method of access can be extended to your personal data structures by making them an instance of the typeclass [Taversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable), see a longer list of example [Traversables in the Lens documentation.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#t:Traversable).

### Nested structures

Digging down into nested structures is simple with the lens [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org).  For example accessing an element in a list of lists:

```
> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] ^? element 0 . element 1
Just 2
> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] ^? element 1 . element 2
Just 6
```

This composition works even when the nested data structures are of different types.  So for example if I had a list of trees:

```
> :{
 let
  tree = Node 1 [
       Node 2 []
     , Node 3 []
     ]
 :}
> putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show $ tree
1
|
+- 2
|
`- 3
> :{
 let 
  listOfTrees = [ tree
      , fmap (*2) tree -- All tree elements times 2
      , fmap (*3) tree -- All tree elements times 3
      ]            
 :}

> listOfTrees ^? element 1 . element 0
Just 2
> listOfTrees ^? element 1 . element 1
Just 4
```

You can nest arbitrarily deeply with arbitrary types as long as they meet the `Traversable` requirement.  So accessing a list of trees of sequences of text is no sweat.

### Changing the nth element

A common operation in many languages is to assign to an indexed position in an array.  In python you might:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[3] = 9
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 9, 5]
```

The 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package gives this functionality with the `(.~)` operator.  Though unlike in python the original list is not mutated, rather a new list is returned.

```
> let a = [1,2,3,4,5]
> a & element 3 .~ 9
[1,2,3,9,5]
> a
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

`element 3 .~ 9` is just a function and the `(&)` operator, part of the 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package, is just reverse function application.  Here it is with the more common function application.

```
> (element 3 .~ 9) [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,9,5]
```

Assignment again works perfectly fine with arbitrary nesting of `Traversable`s.

```
> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] & element 0 . element 1 .~ 9
[[1,9,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: May I suggest linking to `Data.Traversable` rather than the re-export in `lens`?

Comment: @dfeuer - I added a link to Data.Traversable in base. I also kept the old link and pointed out that there was a longer list of example traverables in the Lens documentation.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 13):

The straight answer was already given: Use `!!`.

However newbies often tend to overuse this operator, which is expensive in Haskell (because you work on single linked lists, not on arrays). There are several useful techniques to avoid this, the easiest one is using zip. If you write `zip ["foo","bar","baz"] [0..]`, you get a new list with the indices "attached" to each element in a pair: `[("foo",0),("bar",1),("baz",2)]`, which is often exactly what you need.

Comment: You also need to be careful about your types there. Most of the time you don't want to end up with the indices being slow Integers rather than fast machine Ints. Depending on what exactly your function does and how explicit your typing is, Haskell might infer the type of [0..] to be [Integer] instead of [Int].

Answer (score 8):

You can use `!!`, but if you want to do it recursively then below is one way to do it:

```
dataAt :: Int -> [a] -> a
dataAt _ [] = error "Empty List!"
dataAt y (x:xs)  | y <= 0 = x
                 | otherwise = dataAt (y-1) xs
```

Answer (score 5):

Haskell's standard list data type `forall t. [t]` in implementation closely resembles a canonical C linked list, and shares its essentially properties. Linked lists are very different from arrays. Most notably, access by index is a O(n) linear-, instead of a O(1) constant-time operation.

If you require frequent random access, consider the [`Data.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.1/docs/Data-Array.html) standard.

`!!` is an unsafe partially defined function, provoking a crash for out-of-range indices. Be aware that the standard library contains some such partial functions (`head`, `last`, etc.). For safety, use an option type `Maybe`, or the [`Safe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.14/docs/Safe.html) module.

Example of a reasonably efficient, robust total (for indices ≥ 0) indexing function:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a

lookup :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
lookup _ []       = Nothing
lookup 0 (x : _)  = Just x
lookup i (_ : xs) = lookup (i - 1) xs
```

Working with linked lists, often ordinals are convenient:

```
nth :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
nth _ []       = Nothing
nth 1 (x : _)  = Just x
nth n (_ : xs) = nth (n - 1) xs
```

Comment: These functions recurse forever for negative and nonpositive Ints respectively.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old post ... but it may be useful for someone ...
in a "***functional***" way ...

```
import Data.List

safeIndex :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
safeIndex xs i 
        | (i> -1) && (length xs > i) = Just (xs!!i)
        | otherwise = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

The following function seems ideal because it is not partial (unlike `!!`), and is implemented by an existing library (relude):

```
(!!?) :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-1.0.0.1/docs/Relude-List.html#v:-33--33--63-

```
Prelude> import Relude.List
Prelude Relude.List> ['a'..'f'] !!? 0
Just 'a'
Prelude Relude.List> ['a'..'f'] !!? 100
Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Maybe-way" is a reasonabe approach.

Just to come up with an alternative, where you need to get a default value that you can determine beforehand.

```
atDefault :: a -> Integer -> [a] -> a
atDefault aDef _ [] = aDef                        -- case: is empty anyway
atDefault _ 0  (a:_) = a                          -- case: index is 0 -> take it
atDefault aDef nIndex  (a:la) 
    | nIndex > 0 = atDefault aDef (nIndex - 1) la -- case: index is positive
    | otherwise  = aDef                           -- case: index is negative
```

A use case might be the following:

You want to represent an endless set of numbers by implementing that using list of octets. Assuming the list has always a given set of n elements, assuming n is > 0 - but elements might be also accessed where you would usually consider it out of index range (index >= n or index < 0) - but you don't. Instead you provide 0 as a default.

Example:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Word as W
import qualified Data.Bits as Bts
import Data.Bits ((.|.))
import qualified Data.List as L

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ atDefault 0x00 (-1) myOctet
    print $ atDefault 0x00 0 myOctet
    print $ atDefault 0x00 1 myOctet
    print $ atDefault 0x00 2 myOctet
    print $ atDefault 0x00 3 myOctet
    print $ atDefault 0x00 4 myOctet

myOctet = toOctets (0xA4B3C2D1 :: W.Word32)

atDefault :: a -> Integer -> [a] -> a
atDefault aDef _ [] = aDef                        -- case: is empty anyway
atDefault _ 0  (a:_) = a                          -- case: index is 0 -> take it
atDefault aDef nIndex  (a:la) 
    | nIndex > 0 = atDefault aDef (nIndex - 1) la -- case: index is positive
    | otherwise  = aDef                           -- case: index is negative

class Octetable w where
    toOctets :: w -> [W.Word8]

instance Octetable W.Word32 where
    toOctets w32 = 
        [ fromIntegral (w32 `Bts.shiftR` 24)
        , fromIntegral (w32 `Bts.shiftR` 16)
        , fromIntegral (w32 `Bts.shiftR` 8)
        , fromIntegral w32
        ]
```

Output

```
0
164
179
194
209
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to use [genericIndex :: Integral i => [a] -> i -> a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericIndex) function which is less restrictive in it index type parameter than [(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:-33--33-). Can be handy in some scenarios.