# How to get the nth element of a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following output from my code:

```
['test1', ':', '(', '83.25,', '78.32)', '*33.90*', '2.29', '2.14', '0.82', '65.95', 'test2', ':', '(', '101.80,', '95.10)', '*31.73*', '12.05', '0.60', '0.96', '-26.46', 'test3', ':', '(', '49.84,', '42.29)', '*33.19*', '6.54', '1.24', '0.50', '67.42']
```

I want the 6th, 7th, 16th, 17th, 26th and 27th element of the list and so on for any length If possible putting them in two separate lists. So eventually I would like an output that's just two lists like the following:

```
list1 = [2.29, 12.05, 6.54]
list2 = [2.14, 0.60, 1.24]
```

Does anyone know how to get this result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get nth element from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217171/how-can-i-get-nth-element-from-a-list)

Comment: @abdoulsn - Thats haskell, not python

Comment: @abdoulsn Did you just try to edit the tags (removing "python", adding "haskell") so that your comment is correct?

Comment: You said it’s haskel???

Comment: Your link leads to an haskell answer.

Comment: Ooohh sorry sory I see I posted link to haskel. Sorry

Comment: "I have the following output from my code:" so if you are in control of your code, you should be able to refactor the code such that the output is easier to process. Could you share the code that led to this output?

Answer (score 2):

If your list is called `data` you can do the following.

```
data_starting_at_position_6 = data[6::10]
data_starting_at_position_7 = data[7::10]
```

You start at the correct position and use `10` as the step.

At the moment you have strings in the list, so `data[6::10]` gives you `['2.29', '12.05', '6.54']`. If you would like to have floats you can use `list(map(float, data[6::10]))` and get `[2.29, 12.05, 6.54]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mod of index!

```
6_list = []
7_list = []
for i in xrange(len(your_list) + 1):
    if i%10 == 6:
        6_list.append(your_list[i])
    elif i%10 == 7:
        7_list.append(your_list[i])
```